# Use a list with function names to iteratively apply over a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, list, apply

Context: I'm allowing a user to add specific methods for a cleaning process pipeline (appended to a main list with all the methods chosen). Each element from this list is the name of a function.

My quesiton is:

Why does this work:

```
dataframe[cleanedCol] =dataframe[colToClean].apply(replace_contractions).apply(remove_links).apply(remove_emails)
```

But something like this doesn't?

```
pipeline = ['replace_contractions','remove_links','remove_emails']
for method in pipeline:
     dataframe[cleanedColumn] = dataframe[columnToClean].apply(method)
```

How could I iteratively apply each one of the methods from the list (by the order they are in the list) to the dataframe column?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you tell us what the difference is between `replace_contractions` and `'replace_contractions'`? What are the types of both those expressions? If you're just doing one `.apply()`, would  `dataframe[colToClean].apply('replace_contractions')` work? Why not?

Comment: What you have in the second example is a list of strings, not a list of variables. That's why it returns error when you pass it into the apply method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would either have to [convert those strings to actual function objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string) or even better just store the function objects instead of the names as strings

```
pipeline = [replace_contractions, remove_links, remove_emails]
for method in pipeline:
     dataframe[cleanedColumn] = dataframe[columnToClean].apply(method)
```

Comment: That was my bad, completely forgot about that! I was using a dictionary as a way to map keys as the "function name" and values as the "options chosen" `{function: 1}, etc` and I forgot that I should be using the function objects instead of strings! Thanks!